# Switching between views with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a menu in the sidebar that determines which view is shown in the main content.

I have managed to create it using JQuery but I feel like i'm repeating myself to much in the JQuery code.

Is there a cleaner way of achieving this but making it more scaleable and easy to add elements to without having to add to the JQuery code?

Here is my fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/danjodesigns/9r20sfmb/3/

Any help improving this would be greatly appreciated.

JQuery:

```
$(".settings-btn-1").click(function () {
    $('.settings-menu-btn').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('.settings-view').removeClass("active");
    $('.view-1').addClass("active");
});
$(".settings-btn-2").click(function () {
    $('.settings-menu-btn').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('.settings-view').removeClass("active");
    $('.view-2').addClass("active");
});
$(".settings-btn-3").click(function () {
    $('.settings-menu-btn').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('.settings-view').removeClass("active");
    $('.view-3').addClass("active");
});
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">

    <div class="settings-sidebar">

        <ul class="settings-menu">
           <li class="settings-menu-btn settings-btn-1 active"><span>Account Details</span></li>
           <li class="settings-menu-btn settings-btn-2"><span>Profile Information</span></li>
           <li class="settings-menu-btn settings-btn-3"><span>Categories</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="settings-view-placeholder">

        <section class="settings-view view-1 active">
            <h2>Account Details</h2>
            <p>Review and update your account details.</p>
        </section>

        <section class="settings-view view-2">
            <h2>Profile Information</h2>
            <p>View your profile information.</p>
        </section>

        <section class="settings-view view-3">
            <h2>Categories</h2>
            <p>Review and update your store categories. These tags will determine what shoppers your store is suggested to.</p>
        </section>


    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  width:100%;
}

.settings-sidebar {
  background-color:white;
  margin-right:15px;
}

.settings-menu {
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  width:250px;
}

.settings-menu-btn {
  border-bottom:solid 1px #EEEEEE;
  padding:15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.settings-menu-btn.active {
  background-color:#191919 !important;
  color:#FFFFFF !important;
}

.settings-menu-btn:hover {
  background-color:#F7F7F7;
}

.settings-view-placeholder {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  padding:30px;
  flex-grow:1;
}

.settings-view {
    display: none;
    flex-direction:column;
}

.view-1.active,
.view-2.active,
.view-3.active {
    display: flex !important;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9r20sfmb/4/

Comment: Any reason why this has been down voted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No need for any classes with numbers** .. You can use `li` class `settings-menu-btn` and Then you can use `.index()`  also no need for `view-1 , view-2 ...` you can just use `settings-view` and `.eq()` directly

```js
$("li.settings-menu-btn").click(function () {
    var ThisIndex = $(this).index();
    $('.settings-menu-btn').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('.settings-view').removeClass("active");
    $('.settings-view').eq(ThisIndex).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  width:100%;
}

.settings-sidebar {
  background-color:white;
  margin-right:15px;
}

.settings-menu {
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  width:250px;
}

.settings-menu-btn {
  border-bottom:solid 1px #EEEEEE;
  padding:15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.settings-menu-btn.active {
  background-color:#191919 !important;
  color:#FFFFFF !important;
}

.settings-menu-btn:hover {
  background-color:#F7F7F7;
}

.settings-view-placeholder {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  padding:30px;
  flex-grow:1;
}

.settings-view {
    display: none;
    flex-direction:column;
}

.settings-view.active {
    display: flex !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

    <div class="settings-sidebar">

        <ul class="settings-menu">
           <li class="settings-menu-btn active"><span>Account Details</span></li>
           <li class="settings-menu-btn"><span>Profile Information</span></li>
           <li class="settings-menu-btn"><span>Categories</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="settings-view-placeholder">

        <section class="settings-view active">
            <h2>Account Details</h2>
            <p>Review and update your account details.</p>
        </section>

        <section class="settings-view">
            <h2>Profile Information</h2>
            <p>View your profile information.</p>
        </section>

        <section class="settings-view">
            <h2>Categories</h2>
            <p>Review and update your store categories. These tags will determine what shoppers your store is suggested to.</p>
        </section>


    </div>

</div>
```

and While you won't use `view-1 , view-2 , ...` you need to change

```
.view-1.active,
.view-2.active,
.view-3.active {
    display: flex !important;
}
```

to

```
.settings-view.active {
    display: flex !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor your code using:

```
$('.settings-sidebar').on('click', '.settings-menu-btn:not(.active)', function() {
  $('.settings-view').eq($(this).index()).add(this).add('.active').toggleClass("active");
});
```

### -jsFiddle